# Web ReportViewer authentication

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, reportviewer

I need some help with authentication when using the web reportviewer to view SSRS reports.

In IIS I've set "Windows Authentication" only and unchecked "Anonymous Access" and the other checks in the Directory Security tab. The result in my website is that WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() returns the ASPNET user and Request.LogonUserIdentity the domain account of the user that logged in. On the page that hosts the ReportViewer control, I programmatically impersonate the Request.LogonUserIdentity, then set all the report/server properties and refresh the ServerReport, however this returns the "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized." error and I'm 100% sure the Request.LogonUserIdentity has access to the report. To proof the impersonation worked, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() returns the same user as Request.LogonUserIdentity after the impersonation and I'm using the same impersonation when I need to query the database, just with a specific user.

I've noticed that on the ReportViewer1, the ServerReport property has a property for ImpersonationUser, but I'm not able to set this and can't find where to either.

Can anyone shed some light please! I've been working on this for days now....

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to do impersonation yourself. If you're using Windows Authentication and have disabled anonymous access, then simply let ASP.NET flow the end-user's credentials to Reporting Server. Try adding the `<identity>` element to your web.config file:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Another issue you might be encountering (if your Reporting Server is on a different machine to your web server) is the [NTLM double-hop problem](http://blog.networkfoo.org/?p=127) and you may need to configure Kerberos in order to support credential delegation over multiple machines.